# How can I tell which subroutine I'm in?

Tags: perl, subroutine

Is there a way to get the name of the enclosing subroutine of a piece of perl code?
For example:

```
sub foo { print where_am_i(); }
```

will output `'foo'`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) function:

```
my $function = (caller(0))[3];
```